# Display template before model resolves in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a template in which the data come from a simple jquery .ajax. I too have a template with an ArrayController to put some data in. When I load the page, I want the template linked to the jquery .ajax to display before resolving the model for the other template (because there is a lot of data in the list).

Right now, it waits for all pending xhr requests before displaying any of the templates. What should I do?

Edit : I actually don't think showing code will be useful because apart from having an ajax request on a controller's init function and a model hook, there is nothing special about my code.

All I want to do is :

1 - Make ajax request

2 - Display template with the result of this request

3 - Trigger model hook after the template is on screen

Answer (score 1):

Ember has a special template you can add that will be shown during the loading of a model on a route. I.e. if you have a `foo.bar` template you can add a `foo.bar.loading` template and it will automatically show whilst the route is fetching the model. For more information on loading substates you can check out the [Ember Docs](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/).

Comment: Mmm... You are absolutely right but considering my template comes from an ajax request, could it still work?

Comment: You mean your template isn't precompiled? Maybe you could share the relevant bits of code with us to make it easier to understand and help you with the issue.

Comment: I will update with some code, but the app is getting extremely big so keep in mind there is plenty of things happening in there.

Comment: Just try to post the code that is relevant to the question and try to remove the rest of the code that isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Follow your case IMHO the best way is a Component, for example on My team follow this approach for Dashboard UI where each box (chart) request data independently of Route.

This means we load the template without data and then the component fetch the data.